# Custom property for custom widget in KV lang - kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make a custom widget, it has a property name "MaxHeight", property is working fine, but not in KV file.

My Custom Widget KV code is:

```
<ComboBox>
    displaybox:displaybox
    DropDown:
        id: displaybox
        height: root.height
```

and Python code is :

```
class ComboBox(Button):
    displaybox = ObjectProperty(None)
    #displaybox = DropDown

    Items = dict()
    MaxHeight = NumericProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ComboBox,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(MaxHeight=self.setter("MaxHeight"))
        #self.displaybox.height=self.MaxHeight
        #self.bind(self.displaybox.height=self.setter("MaxHeight"))

    def AddItem(self,Title,Value):
        if Value not in self.Items:
            self.Items[Value] = Title
            tmp = ComboBoxItem(text=Title,Tag=Value,
                               size_hint_y=None,height=32)
            tmp.bind(on_release=lambda tmp: self.UpdateSelected(tmp.text, tmp.Tag))
            self.displaybox.add_widget(tmp)

    def UpdateSelected(self,Text, Value):
        self.displaybox.select(Text)
        self.text=Text

    def on_release(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.displaybox.open(self)

    def Dismiss(self):
        self.displaybox.dismiss(self)

Code of how it is used:
    Label:
        text: 'Branch'
        font_size: FS_B
        text_size: self.size
    ComboBox:
        id: clientsdropdown
        MaxHeight: 20
    Button:
```

When the app starts, error shows as:

```
kivy.lang.ParserException: Parser: File "E:\OS Support\workspace\TestApp\startapp.kv", line 57:
 ...
      55:    ComboBox:
      56:       id: clientsdropdown
 >>   57:       MaxHeight: 20
      58:           
      59:   Button:
```

1. Could you please advice/correct me on how to define custom properties in KV language.
2. I am trying to access this maxheight and set it to DropDown control in ComboBox, is there a way to access the parent widget (of combobox) height to DropDown control.

EDIT:
In the above code I renamed all "MaxHeight" to "listheight", and the code works now, however, when I added the following code, the dropdown height is not getting updated, could you please correct me where I went wrong.
Code:

```
def on_listheight(self,instance,value):
    self.displaybox.height=value
```

I achieved the height with using root.parent.height as advised, but looking to understand why it did not get updated with above property change code and also the below code in Combobox Init section throws a error, saying " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dismiss'", how can I achieve combobox to be dismissed when app started, currently it is being shown open when app started. Thank you.

```
self.displaybox.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties to be used in kv language should start with a lower case letter, as kv uses this to tell them apart from widgets.

> is there a way to access the parent widget (of combobox) height to DropDown control.

I don't entirely understand this question, but in general you can access the parent with self.parent.

Comment: Thank you, the code worked, edited the question, it would ge great if you could educate me on the above change as I see most of the KIVY question on Stackoverflow are answered by you the most. :)